# How do I achive CSS Responsiveness based on viewport aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

When the viewport is wide enough, I require the Title and Subtitle to appear as a single line, without breaking, but when the viewport height is larger and the width is lesser, the Title and Subtitle should be shown as two separate lines. However, neither the Title nor the Subtitle should break (wrap), and should instead, scale to fit, at all viewport sizes.

What I tried was to define multiple staggered @media css queries for different sizes (min-width/max-width, min-height/max-height) and to set the font size, but it becomes too complicated and is not optimal.

```css
#banner { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; font: bold min(calc(3.2vw - 1.7vmin), 8vmin) Arial; padding: 0 0 1ex; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center }
@media (min-height: 60vw) { #banner { font-size: min(calc(6vw - 2.8vh), 4vh) } }
@media (orientation: portrait) { #banner { font-size: 3vw } }
#banner:before, #banner:after { flex-shrink: 0; content: ' '; width: 20vmin; height: 15vmin }
#banner:before, #banner:after { background: center/contain no-repeat url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg) }
#banner > * { margin: 0 1ex; text-align: center }
#banner > * > * { display: inline-block; padding: .3ex }
```

```html
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <span>Just Some Title</span>
      <span>(Just Some Subtitle)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I already have a nifty solution, and this question is intended to facilitate sharing it with others, hoping it will be useful.

The snippet included above is actually the solution to the problem. This was sort of by mistake, possibly due to a bug in the snippet editor (I was trying to edit a snippet with two snippets in the same draft, but the wrong snippet got updated...), as I was using the question space to draft the answer as well. However, I decided to leave this as is for now. Feel free to let me know if I should remove the solution from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this in the wild yet, and not sure how common it is, but it appears to be possible to define an @media query correlating width with height such as min/max-width with vh or min/max-height with vw. This is a little similar to using orientation: landscape/portrait, but allows more fine-grained control over the aspect ratio.

Example:

```css
#banner { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; font: bold min(calc(3.2vw - 1.7vmin), 8vmin) Arial; padding: 0 0 1ex; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center }
@media (min-height: 60vw) { #banner { font-size: min(calc(6vw - 2.8vh), 4vh) } }
@media (orientation: portrait) { #banner { font-size: 3vw } }
#banner:before, #banner:after { flex-shrink: 0; content: ' '; width: 20vmin; height: 15vmin }
#banner:before, #banner:after { background: center/contain no-repeat url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg) }
#banner > * { margin: 0 1ex; text-align: center }
#banner > * > * { display: inline-block; padding: .3ex }
```

```html
  <div id="banner">
    <div>
      <span>Just Some Title</span>
      <span>(Just Some Subtitle)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

To restate, note the distinction that this uses vw units with min-height, not the usual vh with min/max-height. The corresponding can be done with min/max-width + vh units.

Note that the above example was extracted from a more complete solution, and may require finer adjustments to suit your exact requirements/layout.

Also note that I had some issues getting this to work properly as a snippet, but maybe viewing it as full-screen may work. Even though it may not demo properly as a snippet, the solution itself seems to be sound and I have tested a working implementation elsewhere.

I should also note that I'm not exactly sure what's being compared here, apples to oranges. It may indeed be possible to compare apples to oranges if you take the nutritional value or sugar/glucose content or some other similar attribute, and this stands in evidence.

However, you should be aware of the possible caveats. If pixels are being compared here (if the units are being converted to pixel counts, horizontal and vertical, of which I'm not sure), beware that these may not be square on all devices, and I'm not sure if CSS standardizes or mandates the use of square pixels for these measurements/comparisons, meaning, effectively, that the results could possibly vary from device to device or browser to browser. This is just speculation. I don't really know, as I haven't done the necessary research.

Anyhow, for the lack of a better solution, this seems to suffice, meaning, this is all I've got, so far.

I should possibly make a note on the use of the unit vmin in the first expression, while using vh in the second. The @media constraint as defined effectively applies to landscape as portrait gets overridden below, so as far as the second expression is concerned, vh is effectively the same as vmin. If you prefer, it doesn't hurt to substitute vh with vmin. However, the converse would not be applicable to the first expression.

The first and second expressions above are just trial and error approximations for the sake of example. In a real world example, I used expressions like: `min(calc(var(--title-width) / 31), 8vmin)` and `min(calc(var(--title-width) / 16), 4vh)` where `--title-width: calc(100vw - 3.4ex - 40vmin - 16px)` is defined. Here, all widths such as margins, padding, and outer element widths are subtracted. `2 * 8px` for body margin, `2 * 1.2ex` for body padding, `2 * .5ex` for title x/h margin, `2 * 20vmin` for the two small side images. The divisors `31`, `16` are trial and error values to fix the title text size. The exact value would be the width in em of the expected title size or possibly even the ratio of the title width to the title font height (I'm not sure). `8vmin/4vh` is used as a max/upper value for the font size, so the text height doesn't grow beyond the height of the two images when not wrapping. This value should be based on the image height, if you're using such. I didn't try to adapt these for the snippets, as I'm really not sure how vw, vh, vmax, vmin are calculated in snippets.